# Is it ok to put logic inside exceptions?

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, solid-principles, design-principles

I use exceptions extensively, and I often face the dilemma of where to put logic for a very specific exception.

To illustrate let's say that I have implemented my own XML parser which takes a file path, opens the file and parses it. Now in case of parse error I want to throw an exception, which specifies where the incorrect XML is in the file. This is done by outputting message which contains

1. file name
2. line number
3. nearest string contents

Thus far I've been trying to do this by feeding the exception only with scalars, as they may be immediately used in the message. This has become my rule: *as little logic as possible inside exceptions*. And following that rule any computations of the variables used in exception were located outside that exception.

A simplified example:

```
void parseXmlFile(string filePath)
{
    // …

    int line = currentLine();
    string surroundingText = StringHelper.getSurroundingText(filePath, offset);

    throw new SpecificXmlParseError(filePath, line, surroundingText);
}
```

But as my project evolved I've had the need to reuse my exception many times. Each time I was forced to compute the same variables over again, which violated the DRY rule. So I wonder if it would be ok to put the computation logic inside the exception and feed it only with the parameters required for computing the data for the message. It could look like this:

```
class SpecificXmlParseError
{
    void SpecificXmlParseError(filePath, offset) : base(ComputeMessage(filePath, offset))
    {}

    static string ComputeMessage(filePath, offset)
    {
        int line = computeLineBasedOnOffset(filePath, offset);
        string surroundingText = StringHelper.getSurroundingText(filePath, offset);
        string exceptionMessage = putTogetherMessage(surroundingText);
        return exceptionMessage;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The risk here is that the computation logic can throw another exception. But is there a specific reason why this is bad? Only bad thing I can think of is that it would hide the original exception (and the real reason) from any logger that will catch them. But on the other hand the same thing would happen in the first case, where the data is computed before the exception. So are there some additional concerns of which I'm forgetting?

A middle solution would be to write helper class, which would compute the string message. This is the most elegant solution I came up with so far, but it also feels like way to much in this case and violates KISS (after all I just want to throw an exception!).

Is there a win-win solution for this? What are the pros and cons of the solutions?

Comment: Helper methods to build exceptions are pretty common. You could consider it an application of the factory pattern.

Comment: If you're worried about your functions within your exception creation throwing another exception, you could wrap them in a try and swallow them since your overarching issue was the bad XML in the first place.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Ok, I can agree with that. But how is it superior to having the logic inside a constructor?

Comment: @theSilentOne Oh no! Don't swallow any exceptions. Or at least don't tell out loud that you do this ;)

Comment: Even in this situation you think it's still bad? Normally, I would say no but it seems OK here. I'm no expert (fresh graduate) but it seems like a decent solution here.

Comment: It's ALWAYS bad! Suppose the file would be located on another server, which has gone down. You would hide the information about hardware malfunction. And no one would be able to figure out why it does not work.

Comment: @theSilentOne We commonly catch lower level exceptions and throw a new one using the `InnerException` to point to the lower level exception. That way the final exceptions matches the outermost abstraction layer, but we don't lose any information about the original cause.

Answer (score 0):

> The risk here is that the computation logic can throw another
>   exception. But is there a specific reason why this is bad?

Because exception-driven code may be overcomplicated and difficult to understand and thus expensive to maintain.

But in this case (for error handling purposes) I think it is not bad at all.

I believe the first thing you need to do is to *log* the exception to a log file, or to standard error stream. Then you are sure that original cause of the problem is not lost. Then even if exception handling code fails you still have a chance to investigate.

If your software is mission-critical then I would make sure the error reporting code is bug free - for example, I would cover it with extensive unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

> The risk here is that the computation logic can throw another exception. But is there a specific reason why this is bad?

I think throwing another exception is a fact of any exception handling, unless you just stop all execution. It depends on what you want to do. Exception handling has its risks as a paradigm, but you can't eliminate them entirely. I don't think that your alternatives makes the risk any worse. I'm not sure I understand entirely this part of your question.

As for DRY, it suggests creating helper classes to handle errors if you end up with the same logic in the handling. An overarching design principle is ["pick your battles"](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/protectedVariation.pdf#page=2) a.k.a. depends on what you value as important. DRY is often in conflict with KISS, but not always. They are rules of thumb. Design is non-deterministic and a problem that is wicked (once you make a decision to solve part of the problem, you've changed the problem). Don't strive to have everything *win-win*. Strive for *acceptable*.

Exceptions are a way to *detect* errors and eventually specify logic on how to handle them. If that logic becomes complex or hard to maintain, then create specialized (highly cohesive) classes for it. In your case of XML parse errors, it's not really that complex (you're just outputting information that is useful for the user to help fix the fault in the XML). I think [Grzegorz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22619095/1168342) sums that part up well by saying to just log it.

In the *Error Handler (30)* pattern in his book [Patterns for Fault Tolerant Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470319798), Robert Hanmer says, "Separate error processing code in special handling blocks for easier maintenance and to facilitate new handlers being added in the future." This book has a lot of great advice related to fault-tolerant software patterns.

Your example of reporting information (file name, line number, surrounding text) about the XML error is precisely an example of the *Fault Observer (10)* pattern from the same book. Users are the "interested observers" of this kind of fault; observers in this pattern don't have to be internal parts of the system.

[Convert exceptions](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ConvertExceptions) is a pattern that's useful where there are layers. It's similar to Hanmer's *Escalation (9)* pattern.

XML Parsing errors cannot really be recovered by your application. [Some approaches help the user try to fix them by guessing](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki/Parse-Error-Handling). But that is probably overkill for your XML example (not sure how important it is to your problem). If you have an XSD for the input, you can get pretty good validation and useful error messages (but I've never coded it - just used it in IDEs like Eclipse or VisualStudio).